# Time not adding

Tags: java, date, time

I'm trying to get it to be 12 hours ahead of what it is, it doesn't work but anything lower works, unsure on how to fix it.

```
package New;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
public class DateManipulation {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date = new Date();
    String test = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy").format(date);
    System.out.println(test);
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    try {
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+43200000l);
        String time = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(time);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

HMU With any solutions

Comment: Btw I've tried making a long variable with the value of 43200000l then tried adding but still didn't working, been stuck on this for 30 minutes and haven't found anything.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to note is `h` in [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) represents the *"Hour in am/pm (1-12)"*

So, 10am + 12 is 10pm, but since you've not supplied a formatter for the am/pm marker, it's basically just `10`...

Now days, the preferred method would be to use Java 8's Time API or Joda-Time, for example...

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss").format(dateTime));
LocalDateTime later = dateTime.plusHours(12);
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss").format(later));
```

Which outputs...

```
02-23-16 10:27:27
02-23-16 22:27:27
```

I've deliberately used `HH` to show that it works

Comment: Sorry, I clicked the wrong place. Deleted.

Comment: @BasilBourque 

Answer (score 0):

Try the new Date&Time API ([java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)) of Java 8 and later. It is much more simple. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.now(); 
LocalTime newTime = time.plusHours(12);
```

Comment: But it they use a format of `hh:mm:ss` in `DateTimeFormatter`, they'll still have the same problem

Comment: As you said  "_since you've not supplied a formatter for the am/pm marker, it's basically just 10_"

Comment: So, the point been, the answer isn't "use Java 8's Time API" (although highly recommended), the answer is, use a better format ;)

Comment: Also, I suggest always specifying the desired/expected time zone when calling `.now` rather than implicitly relying on the JVM’s current default time zone. `LocalTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )`